# Vue 2: fetch accessing `/api/api/X` instead of `/api/X`?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue.

I'm trying to access something like:

```
async getIngredients() {
  let response = await fetch("/api/ingredients/");
},
```

within the `methods` of my Vue 2 component.

But my backend application (Django) reports me that:

```
Not Found: /api/api/ingredients/
"GET /api/api/ingredients/ HTTP/1.1" 404
```

I searched all my code, but can't understand why this is happening. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What happens if you omit the `/api` part in your `fetch` call? Maybe Django is setup to expect calls coming in at route `/api` per default, so what then could happen is that root path `/api` is hit with "subroute" `/api/X`.

Comment: I tried that.. and if I ommit the first `/api` part, the backend just doesn't get the request at all

Comment: Just a blind guess...But what happens if you omit the trailing slash at `ingredients/` ?

Comment: Try giving it a more absolute path, ie include localhost, the ip address, or whatever domain you are running this on

Comment: @Jacob It is working fine when using absolute paths. I'm attempting to deploy it in a Heroku server. So I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://johnfraney.ca/posts/2019/05/14/integrate-django-vuejs/